# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. I'm using Postgresql

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've tried everything, it seems to me. But it always gives me error "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured."
These are my pom.xml and application.properties files.

```
...
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.24</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

```
#https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:5432//localhost/gamestudio
spring.datasource.username=<my username>
spring.datasource.password=<my password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=2
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gamestudio
spring.datasource.username=<my username>
spring.datasource.password=<my password>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=<create | create-drop | update | validate | none>
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

I changed my pom.xml several times,
I even ckecked application.properties, I've tried two different methods at the end of this question, I don't really understand the difference, but nothing helped.